# Headers and multiple sources

Tags: c, header

Hey. I have this in a header file:

```
struct something {
        int a;
        int b;
};
int all[25][9];
```

This header file is included in all 3 .c files that I have on my project. One of the files (the main file) has the main function and the others have functions that are used in the main file. They also use variables that are declared on this main file, by using extern type variableName. However, while I do declare `struct something *stuff;` and later malloc it on the main file (and these other files work with this `stuff` directly), my `all` 2d array isn't declared anywhere but the header file. I use this array in one of those extra .c files. Will this `all` array be declared in each of them? Should I do it this way? It's imperative that there's a reference to `all` in that header file, for my purposes. Should I just declare `all` as `all[][]` and then assign a size to it on the .c file, or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want multiple source files to share a single array called `all` you should declare

```
extern int all[25][9];
```

in the header *and*

```
int all[25][9];
```

in **one** of the c files.

Comment: Better yet, use a typedef in the header so you don't someday end up with someone changing the header and not the definition, or vice versa.

Comment: @John Zwinck: You should get a compilation error in that case, as long as you include the header in the file that defines it too.

Answer (score 2):

Use extern keyword to declare the array in your header:

```
extern int all[25][9];
```

Then instantiate it in just one of the implementation files:

```
int all[25][9];
```

Other C files include the header and can access the array.

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* do it this way.  This way creates a definition of `all` in every source file that includes the header, and multiple definitions of the same object are not allowed (in pratice, you might get a seperate instance of `all` in each source file, or they might all refer to the same one).

Instead, in the header file, put only declarations:

```
extern int all[25][9];
```

Then in *one* C file (probably your "main" file you mention), put the definition:

```
int all[25][9];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the header file define/declare as

```
EXT int a;
```

In the main c file use

#

```
define EXT  extern
#include <a.h>
#undef EXT
```

This will avoid seperate definition /declaration